# how to centre two fading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to lay out some HTML so that I have the heading then the image then a link. I have been trying to do this but have had no luck, currently the images aren't included in the wrapper for whatever reason and appears after both the header and link. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>heading</h3>
    <div id="cycler">
      <img class="active" src="/images/baker-own-goal.jpg" alt="My image" style="width:600px;height:400px;"/>
      <img src="/images/Oops.jpg" alt="My image" style="width:600px;height:400px;"/>    
    </div>
  <a href="/">Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cycler{
  position:relative;
}
#cycler img{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
#cycler img.active{
  z-index:3;
}
.wrapper{
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 260px;
  margin-left: 260px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;  
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 50px; 
}
.title { 
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Not sure if the JS affects it but will include it anyway:

```
          function cycleImages(){
              var $active = $('#cycler .active');
              var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
              $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
              $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
                  $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
                  $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
              });
          }
          $(document).ready(function(){
          // run every 5s
          setInterval('cycleImages()', 5000);
          })
```

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/492s6ufx/

Comment: position:absolute on the images will mean they are not positioned within their containing elements. I would remove that for starters and maybe post a fiddle of some sort. You might get more help then

Comment: my bad I've included a jsfiddle now, without the position absolute the images won't display on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** : I guess you wants this

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/www18ccq/5/)

```
setInterval(function()
{
    // Remove .active class from the active li, select next li sibling.
    var next = $('img.active').removeClass('active').next('img');

    // Did we reach the last element? Of so: select first sibling
    if (!next.length) next = next.prevObject.siblings(':first');

    // Add .active class to the li next in line.
    next.addClass('active');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Almost yes, except with the images on top of each other so as one fades in the other fades out

Comment: That is what I want thank you, is it possible to make the effect more of a fade in and out rather than the sudden change of image?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right, but you need to give to `cycler` the dimensions of the images, because if you set it's contents to `position:absolute` it won't adapt it's size to wrap them because it's supposed they aren't contained in it anymore. So you should add this to `cycler`'s style:

```
#cycler{
  position:relative;
  width:640px;
  height:480px;
}
```